# Changing file extensions using argparse in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, argparse

I want to change the file extensions of a given csv file to a xml extension or vice versa. At the command line, i can input the following

```
Boo a.csv.                   giving   a.xml
Boo a.xml.                   giving   a.csv
Boo a.csv -out shoes.xml     giving   shoes.xml
```

here is my updated code:

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
import csv
import indent
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

def get_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Converts CSV to XML")
    parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose',action='store_true',dest='verbose',help='Increases messages being printed to stdout')
    parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="Please input the name of the CSV file")
    parser.add_argument('-o','--outputfile',help='(optional) Output file name',nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ext = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[1].lower()
    if args.outputfile is None:
        if ext == ".csv":
            args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.xml'

        elif ext == ".xml":
            args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.csv'
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Invalid extension %s\n' % ext)
        sys.exit(1)
    return args

def main(argv):
    args = get_args(argv[0:])
    if args is None:
        return 1
    reader = read_csv(args.inputfile)
    if args.verbose:
        print ('Verbose Selected')
    if args.verbose:
        print ('Convert to XML with set name')
    generate_xml(reader, args.outputfile)
    return 0 

def read_csv(inputfile):
    return list(csv.reader(inputfile))

def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)        
    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i > 0:
            x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
            if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

                collar = SubElement (current_group, 'collar',{'':', '.join((x1,y1,z1))}),
                toe = SubElement (current_group, 'toe',{'':', '.join((x2,y2,z2))})
                cost = SubElement(current_group, 'cost',{'':cost})
        i+=1
    head.set('total_holes', '%s'%i)
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Now i get an error at x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row and it is a value error that says: need more than one value to unpack

Comment: What's the *tree* variable?

Comment: also its bad form to say `== None` use `is None` or better yet `if not args.outputfile:`

Comment: Use a python debugger such as idle, eric or komodo. Just a few minutes stepping through the code and the answer will be clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not assign the extension to *ext*. The extension is the second item returned by splitext. You should also have another else condition for the case when ext is neither .xml or .csv. This error path would have shown you the problem.

EDIT: Your code has other problems, so I'm adding some comments marked as TODO. You shouldn't mix argument parsing with the implementation of the program. So, the places you are calling tree.whatever() should be done after you've cleaned up your arguments. You'll find you only have to call tree.whatever() once, at the end.

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
import csv
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Converts CSV to XML")
parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="Please input the name of the CSV file")
parser.add_argument('-o','--outputfile',help='(optional) Output file name',nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()

ext = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[1].lower()
if args.outputfile is None:
    if ext == ".csv":
        args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.xml'
        tree.write(args.outputfile) # TODO: There is no 'tree' defined
    elif ext == ".xml":
        args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.csv'
        tree.write(args.outputfile) # TODO: There is no 'tree' defined
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Invalid extension %s\n' % ext)
        sys.exit(1)

# TODO: This should be removed completely
if args.outputfile:
    args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.outputfile)[1] #handles the condition if there is an outputfile set by the user
# TODO: create tree and do the work here
```

Comment: ok thanks, i have incorporated tree into this can i show you my updated code?

Comment: @Andy, you can update your post with the new code. Personally, I find it less confusing if you put it at the bottom of your current post with a note that you've changed it.

Comment: @Andy, since args.inputfile is a file name, it needs to be opened before being passed to csv.reader. Change `reader = read_csv(args.inputfile)` to `reader = read_csv(open(args.inputfile))`